# Comparing a file to another file

Tags: python, file, if-statement, compare, line

```
import sys
import os
import glob
directorylist = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

for directory in directorylist:
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "tobecompared(*).txt")):
        with open(file) as f:
                a=0
                fdata = f.readlines()
                for line in fdata:
                    with open ("/Users/Student/Desktop/folder/pool.txt", "r") as pool:
                        if line in pool:
                            a=a+1
                print a
```

I want to compare lines in text files (tobecompared1.txt, tobecompared2.txt) to the lines in another text file (pool.txt). 
The folder contains the folders A, B, C, and D. 
The pool.txt is in the folder while the tobecompared(*).txt files are in the directories A, B, C. This code aims to print the no. of lines in the tobecompared text files that are present in the original pool.

This code prints 0 repeatedly, so I'm guessing there is an issue with the loops that increases the value of a by 1.
What is really aimed at is:

Say the pool.txt is

```
A
B
C
D
```

tobecompared(01).txt in A is

```
A
A
F
H
C
B
```

tobecompared(02).txt in A is

```
A
B
C
```

tobecompared(01).txt in B is

```
G
D
C
```

The output would be:

```
4
3
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a string inside a file object. That condition will never become true. Replace:

```
if line in pool: 
    a=a+1
```

With:

```
for line2 in pool:
    if line.rstrip() == line2.rstrip():
        a += 1
```

Comment: Would this match identical lines or if there are similar lines that have some identical words would this also count them? It is important for the lines to be identical...

Comment: This will compare each line from tobeCompared against each line in pool.txt; only if they are identical, will the counter be incremented. Try it out